# Addressing in x86

Tags: assembly, x86, addressing

I have got a problem with addressing in x86. Can someone tell me what this does:

```
mov 4000(%ecx, %ebx, 4), %eax
```

Answer (score 1):

An address is computed as 4000 plus the value in the %ecx register plus 4 times the value in the %ebx register. A 32-bit value is loaded from that address and put into the %eax register.

Comment: I find Intel syntax more intuitive that AT&T regards to addressing. In Intel syntax `mov 4000(%ecx, %ebx, 4), %eax` would be `mov eax,[ecx+4*ebx+4000]`.